# Salesforce Backup Process

Tags: security, metadata, data, backup

I would like to be informed about Salesforce Backup Process (Security Management). I would like to know more about the Standard Recovery Process if any.

1. How often is the Salesforce backup taken? Would I have a subset of my client's data or the total data set as retrieved in a specific timestamp?
2. In case of total disaster, which process should be followed to recover my data?
3. Is there an extra cost for Salesforce Data Recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of what's available to you for free, the [Best practices to backup Salesforce data](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334121&type=1) lists:

> - Data Export Service: Manual or scheduled exports of your data via the    UI. [Export Backup Data from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_exportdata.htm&type=5).
> - Data Loader: Manual on-demand exports of your data via the API.    [Export Data](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exporting_data.htm&type=5).
> - Report Export: Manual on-demand exports of your data via reports.    [Export a Report.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_export.htm&type=5)

If you do some sort of custom work with the API, you could have a high frequency of backups (assuming you don't hit API limits), but the Data Export Service allows you to only generate backup files manually once very 7 days as it's most frequent option (and it could be delayed).

If, you haven't backed it up by taking those actions above, there is still the [Salesforce Data Recovery Service](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/updates-to-salesforces-backup-and-restore-services) (was reintroduced after being announced it was going to be retired), but it is paid and is not a quick turnaround from my prior experience. It's essentially a *last resort* option where you create a case with Salesforce.

All of the above is only concerned with data *backup*. I would argue, the recovery or restore process is just as important and the more difficult to tackle. The above may leave you with many excel/csv files, but I would argue it would be near impossible to restore a large data loss from that type of backup. Imagine attempting to insert records across many different objects with x amount of relationships between them - that's the challenge. There's nothing, as far as I'm aware, in free tools to help with this situation.

Hence, why paid service exist to tackle both data backup & *restore*. There's the [Ultimate Guide to Salesforce Backup Solution](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-backup/)s which lists various services

> OwnBackup
>
> Spanning Backup
>
> Gearset
>
> Odaseva
>
> CloudAlly

Salesforce did recently mention a [pilot](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/updates-to-salesforces-backup-and-restore-services) for a Salesforce backup and restore service built natively on the Platform.

> Finally, based on customer feedback, we are pleased to announce that we will **pilot Salesforce backup and restore services built natively on the Platform this summer. We’ve co-designed these services with customers and we expect to deliver the performance, speed, and scale** that you’ve come to expect from the Salesforce Platform while continuing to provide additional ways to innovate and extend these capabilities through our vibrant ecosystem.

Edit: [Backup & Restore](https://www.salesforce.com/products/platform/solutions/data-security/backup-restore-data-recovery/) was announced at Dreamforce 2021 and now [Generally Available](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_backup_restore_ga.htm&type=5&release=234) with Winter '22

Comment: Thank you Kris!

Answer (score 0):

**Salesforce Data recovery service (Paid Service) is already closed on Previous year by Salesforce.**

Currently you can take a org backup by using below 2 ways,

1. Native existing method: [Export Backup Data from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_exportdata.htm&type=5) (It's used to take a backup from specific time or weekly/monthly basis).
2. You can use some partner build application in app exchange to recover salesforce data with this [link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=backup&searchType=simpleSearch).

So please let me know if it helps.